# How do I move a child row to a new parent in Tabulator?

Tags: tabulator

I am using Tabulator version 4.8 with dataTree:true and movableRows:true. After I move a row, how can I discover if a change in parent-child relationship has occurred based on where the row was dropped so I can update the database via Ajax with that new parent-child information?

The only reason I need movable rows is to allow the user to change a row's parent within the same table, but I can not find a way to do that. Using the rowClick and rowMoved callbacks I see that after moving a row the row's index and parent do not change and the row position is always position=-1. I do not see any parent-child information in the row object.

```
var table = new Tabulator("#tree", {
  columns: [{title:"Subject", 
             field:"title"},
            {title:"Value",
             field:"value"}],
  ajaxURL: "/admin.php",
  ajaxParams: {
    ac:"rt",   // ac=action (RetrieveTree)
    tb:"tree", // tb=name of this tree
  },
  dataTree: true,
  movableRows: true,
  rowClick: rowClicked,
  rowMoved: rowMoved
});

// A row was clicked
function rowClicked(e, row) {
  position = row.getPosition();
  parentIndex = row.getTreeParent().getIndex()
  console.log("Row index "+row.getIndex()+" was clicked.\nPosition="+position+"\nParentIndex="+parentIndex);
}

// A row was moved
function rowMoved(row) {
  position = row.getPosition();
  parentIndex = row.getTreeParent().getIndex()
  console.log("Row index "+row.getIndex()+" was moved.\nPosition="+position+"\nParentIndex="+parentIndex);
}
```

console.log output from rowClick before move:

```
Row index 456 was clicked.
Position=-1
ParentIndex=269
```

console.log output from rowMoved after move to different parent:

```
Row index 456 was moved.
Position=-1
ParentIndex=269
```

Answer (score 0):

Tabulator still does not support moving childs between parents
https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/1604#issuecomment-441810722